# Arranging items in rows and columns in ionic2

Tags: angular, grid-layout, ionic2

I need to arrange buttons in a matrix format as shown [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMKgoM) . I am trying to get reproduce this in an app ionic2 mobile app.
This is my attempt to convert it to angular2 `*ngFor` and `*ngIf`.

```
 <div *ngFor="tag in item.tags;let tagIndex = index">
        <div class="row" *ngIf="index % 3 == 0">
          <div *ngFor="i in [0,1,2]">
            <div *ngIf="(tagIndex + i)<item.tags.length"
                <button style="margin:5px">{{item.tags[tagIndex+i]}}</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
  </div>
```

I did not even show the buttons. I tried using `<ion-row>` and `<ion-col>` tags of `ionic2`. It worked. But, the buttons are not uniformly placed as shown below.

[image]

The code to display using `<ion-row>` is this...

```
<ion-row id="footer">
    <ion-col style="margin:5px 5px 5px 5px" *ngFor="let tag of item.tags">
        <button [innerHtml]="tag" (click)="tagClicked($event, tag)"></button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

**css**

```
#footer {
    float:left;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;        
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    display:flex;
}
```

If using `<ion-row>` is the better approach since the framework takes care of displaying all the tags in a gridlayout, how should I make them arrange with uniform distance ?

Comment: doest it wok remove the css from ion-col and <button small [innerHtml]="tag" (click)="tagClicked($event, tag)"></button>

Comment: The columns are still not uniform. I updated the question with the css entry for `"footer"`

Comment: reason behind adding footer id css keep ionic tags default as much as possible... Add a code on plnkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now. I had few syntax errors in my earlier code. For eg.,

```
 <div *ngFor="tag in item.tags;let tagIndex = index"> .
```

Instead of `of` I put `in`. Now with the code fixed, I am able to get the buttons uniformly displayed. This is the final code.

```
<div  *ngFor="let tag of item.tags;let tagIndex = index">
         <div id="footer" *ngIf="tagIndex % 3 == 0">
              <div *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2]">
                <button class="col" style="margin:5px" *ngIf="(tagIndex + i) < item.tags.length" class="col" style="margin:5px">{{item.tags[tagIndex +i]}}</button>
                </div>
         </div>
  </div>
```

The css remains the same.